# AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT' while installing in Juypter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, seaborn, jupyter

I tried installing the `seaborn` module in Jupyter notebook, but I received errors while installing it.

```
AttributeError: module 'pexpect' has no attribute 'TIMEOUT'
```

The below image is image of the juypter error:
[image]

Comment: Try `!pip install seaborn`

Comment: Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/354577) Instead, format code as a [code block]. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.

Comment: import piplite; await piplite.install(['package1', 'package2'])